Adding PostGis to docker/compose.yaml
I am familiar with postgres:16-alpine. With the following compose.yaml and connectionstring postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/postgres it works:
services:
  server:
    container_name: configurator-server
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - gomodcache:/go/pkg/mod
    ports:
      - 50031:8080
      - 50032:12345
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - myNetwork
      - default

  db:
    container_name: configurator-db
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      PGUSER: postgres
    ports:
      - 50033:5432
    volumes:
      - ./initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10

  adminer:
    container_name: configurator-adminer
    image: adminer:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 50034:8080

volumes:
  gomodcache: null
  dbdata: null

networks:
  myNetwork:
    name: MyNetwork

Now I am trying to add kartoza/postgis:16-3.4 to my project, updated compose.yaml with following values:
environment:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgres
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS: postgis,postgis_raster

When run, in the log i see:
postgres ready
configurator-db       | Creating user postgres
configurator-db       |  [Entrypoint] Creating/Updating user  postgres  
configurator-db       | 2024-06-05 12:34:51.746 UTC [220] root@root FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
configurator-db       | ALTER ROLE
configurator-db       | Creating user replicator
configurator-db       |  [Entrypoint] Creating/Updating user  replicator  
configurator-db       | CREATE ROLE
configurator-db       |  [Entrypoint] Database  postgres  already exists 

and it prints root@root FATAL:  role "root" does not exist every second.
What's wrong? I am working on WSL2 Windows 11.
